# Outputing Results from EXECUTE IMMEDIATE PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a script that queries ALL_TAB_COLUMNS does some aggregation then is executed via

```
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vSelect into v_output;
```

at first i v_output was a integer and the vSelect did a count(*) and it returned the row count. I want to change vSelect to an actual

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS <MY_WHERE_CLAUSE>
```

and output the results using DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE. I am going to set it up to write to a log file as soon as I can get it to output, but trying to get it to output first. Oracle 11G

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is to use a nested table of a record variable of `all_tab_columns%rowtype` and then loop through it for displaying.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
    DECLARE
         TYPE tab_all_tab_rec IS
              TABLE OF all_tab_columns%rowtype;
         trec             tab_all_tab_rec;
         v_where_clause   CLOB := 'WHERE OWNER = ''HR''';
    BEGIN
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * 
         FROM all_tab_columns ' || v_where_clause BULK COLLECT
         INTO trec;
         FOR i IN trec.first..trec.last LOOP
              dbms_output.put_line(trec(i).owner || ',' || trec(i).table_name || ',' || trec(i).column_name
              ); --Other columns
         END LOOP;
  END;
  /
```

**O/p**

```
HR,COUNTRIES,COUNTRY_NAME
HR,COUNTRIES,COUNTRY_ID
HR,COUNTRIES,REGION_ID
HR,DEPARTMENTS,LOCATION_ID
HR,DEPARTMENTS,MANAGER_ID
HR,DEPARTMENTS,DEPARTMENT_NAME
HR,DEPARTMENTS,DEPARTMENT_ID
HR,EMPLOYEES,DEPARTMENT_ID
HR,EMPLOYEES,MANAGER_ID
HR,EMPLOYEES,COMMISSION_PCT
HR,EMPLOYEES,SALARY
HR,EMPLOYEES,JOB_ID
HR,EMPLOYEES,HIRE_DATE
HR,EMPLOYEES,PHONE_NUMBER
HR,EMPLOYEES,EMAIL
HR,EMPLOYEES,LAST_NAME
HR,EMPLOYEES,FIRST_NAME
HR,EMPLOYEES,EMPLOYEE_ID
..
..

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a similar method to @Kaushik's, but uses a cursor loop instead of a collection:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  l_cursor sys_refcursor;
  l_row all_tab_columns%rowtype;
  l_where_clause varchar2(50) := q'[where owner = 'HR']';
begin
  open l_cursor for 'SELECT * FROM all_tab_columns ' || l_where_clause;
  loop
    fetch l_cursor into l_row;
    exit when l_cursor%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line(l_row.owner ||','|| l_row.table_name ||','|| l_row.column_name);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

which also gets:

```
HR,REGIONS,REGION_NAME
HR,REGIONS,REGION_ID
HR,LOCATIONS,COUNTRY_ID
HR,LOCATIONS,STATE_PROVINCE
HR,LOCATIONS,CITY
...
```

Although this is doing individual single-row fetches, in recent releases Oracle optimises to use bulk operations in the background, so the performance should be similar to an explicit `bulk collect`, just without needing the collection type.

This assumes you are actually using `select *` in your query so there is a table to use for `%rowtype`. If the query is more selective (which is usually a good thing) or combines multiple tables then you would need to declare a matching record type instead.